# Showing DIV with custom effect using jquery

Tags: jquery

my full script is running but when i click on div then div is not getting hide but i have written code to hide it....can any one tell me where i made the mistake.

here is my code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.lnkcss 
{
    margin-left:350px;
}

.BusyStyles
    {
        background-image: url('images/ajax-loader.gif');
        background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; 
    }

 #transition {

display:none;
position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:50;
border:1px solid #666;
width:100px; height:100px;
}

</style>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lnk').click(function (e) {
            $('body').append('<div id="transition"></div>').show();

            var $t = $('#transition'),
            to = $(this).offset(),
            td = $(document);

            //$t.children('div').css({ width: 100, height: 100 });
            $t.css({
                top: to.top + 50,
                left: to.left + 50,
                display: 'block'
            }).animate({
                top: td.height() / 2,
                left: td.width() / 2
            }, 600, function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    top: '-=75',
                    left: '-=50'
                }, 600);

                $(this).animate({
                    width: 250,
                    height: 200
                }, 600, function () {
                    $('#transition').addClass("BusyStyles");

                });
            });
            return false;
        });

        $('#transition').click(function (e) {
            alert('pp');
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<a href="#" id='lnk' class="lnkcss">FeedBack</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>

$('#transition').click(function (e) {
            alert('pp');
            $(this).hide();
        });
```

the above line i wrote to hide div but it is nothing happen when i click on div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is applied on every '#transition' element that exists at the time, you try to instantiate the handler. You don't have such an element at this time, as it's created dynamically.

You can apply the event handler right after creating the element:

http://jsfiddle.net/Du5k8/

Comment: one major things that the above script not working same way in IE 8. please run the script in IE and u will look the difference. so what will be good fix for IE. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$('body').append('<div id="transition"></div>')` adding the element to the page after the document has been processed requires you `bind any event handlers` to a static parent element.

```
$('#transition').click(function (e) {
    alert('pp');
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Should be changed to

```
$('body').on('click', '#transition', function (e) {
    alert('pp');
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: sorry ur script did not work. i am using jquery version jquery-1.4.1.min.js. ur script gives error. anyway thnxfor attempts.

Comment: @Thomas you should upgrade your jQuery. `.on()` is exlusive to jQuery 1.7 +. There will be no downfall from upgrading.

Comment: one major things that the above script not working same way in IE 8. please run the script in IE and u will look the difference. huge flicker occur. please go to this url http://jsfiddle.net/Du5k8/ and if u know the good fix for IE then please tell me in detail what to change. thanks.

Comment: @Thomas I have zero transitional issue with this animation in IE8. The 'flicker' you may be referring to is based on your CPU's floating integer processing ability. If your processor is week, the animation will hurt you.

Comment: so please guide me what i can do as a result animation will look good & flicker free in low CPU strength. please guide. thanks

Comment: @Thomas unfortunately the answer is to use CSS3. The other option is to change `$.fx.step` which is the `amount in milliseconds jQuery will perform a layout change`. [step: function(now, fx) {}](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). You can see how step is called here.

Comment: can u please help me to construct the reverse effect. here is demo url here is demo url http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/kPZrZ/2/ please have a look and guide me how to develop another routine to create opposite effect when user click on div. thanks